# Can we use the same APi key for all Google APIs

Tags: android, google-api

i have a Android application wherre is use the google Map api.
I have the generated key for the google map Api.
But if i want to use other Api like Google Places Api, can i use the same key as the one i used for the google map?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, you can check this question <Br> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023930/is-it-possible-to-use-maps-and-place-api-with-same-api-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read it [Types of API keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#types-of-api-keys)

> Apps of the same platform type can use the same key.