# How we can add Dynamic API key for google maps in android, from Google maps V2?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any method to add Dynamic key for google maps android after they moved storage of API key from manifest to resource folder. If sharedpreferences is the solution then how to retrieve the key from sharepreferences in Xml file where key will be stored.

Comment: please check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37024676/5068931)

Comment: I checked but not relavant to problem I'm looking for. I want to know how we can add API key as a variable or add it during runtime?

Comment: why should you have to store just declare in manifest

Comment: I want it to change dynamically before loading the map, if we store in manifest file it will be compiled and can't be changed at run time.

Comment: but that key is unique and why should you have to do that?

Comment: i cant understood your concept what you want and here no any kind of pricing for google map, here you can use to one unique key for add google map, and explain your code with some of code or any demo link , doc link etc,

Comment: This is against the Directions API Terms of Service